# How to produce fumes in chemistry lab?

Tags: experimental-chemistry

In chemistry lab we perform experiments to find the unknown solution. I just want to produce some fumes in lab. We are only allowed to use few common dilute solution like $\ce{NH_4Cl}$, $\ce{NH_4OH},$ $\ce{HCl}$, and few more which are generally allowed to students.

Is it possible to form fumes in lab?

Comment: Why would you want to produce nasty smelling and potentially harmful gasses in the lab? This just sounds very insane to me.

Comment: @Martin frankly speaking, my practicals are over in 15-20 minutes but my lab teacher wants that we should be there for at least 45 minutes.But after this she will not force us!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aqueous ammonia and hydrochloric acid are solutions of gases.

In a **fume hood** place two beakers with aliquots of these two solutions (one in each beaker, **don't mix**) side to side.

**Did I mention the fume hood?**

You'll see the formation of solid ammonium chloride from the reaction of the two gases.

$$\ce{HCl(g) + NH3(g) -> NH4Cl(s)}$$

**Don't forget to clean up the mess!**

Comment: I wanted to know with liquid solution, is it possible?